# Get notification when twilio call is picked up

Tags: python, telephony, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm building a twilio app and would like to get notified when a call made using twilio is picked up. I'm using the python api to make the call, like so:

```
call = client.calls.create(to=number,
                           from_="15555555555",
                           url=twiml_url,
                           status_callback=status_url)
```

This all works fine. I get notified when the call is made, by a POST to twiml_url and a POST to status_url when the call ends. In both of these cases I get passed the *CallStatus*, in the first with the value *'ringing'*, in the second *'completed'*

Now, I have read the API docs and know that they say that this is the expected behaviour.

What I'm wondering is, is if there is any way to get a similar kicks for the other *CallStatus* changes? According to Twilio, all of the following are possible values for *CallStatus*:

*queued*, *ringing*, *in-progress*, *completed*, *failed*, *busy* or *no-answer*

It seems kind of pointless to have all the different *CallStatus*'s yet not provide callbacks for them.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is to detect when a call is picked up. The only way I can see of doing this currently is by polling periodically and manually checking if the *CallStatus* has changed - hardly great.

Comment: call.status after making this call should be queued or ringing. twiml_url should get at least in-progress. is that url getting called with status=ringing?

Comment: You are right. twiml_url does in fact get in-progress. I was just being stupid. Thanks for your help. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here. We've added a rad new feature to our API that I'm pretty stoked about called [Call Progress Events](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/monitoring-call-progress-events-with-node-js-and-express.html). It allows a developer to pass a list of events about their call, such as ringing or completed, that they want to be notified about with their call. I think it may help a bit with this use case because you could tell the API to just notify you when a call is answered by using this code:

```
call = client.calls.create(
    url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to="+14155551212",
    from_="+18668675309",
    method="GET",
    status_callback="https://www.myapp.com/events",
    status_callback_method="POST",
    status_events=["answered"],
)
```

If you're not using Python, [this example in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-4) will let you see how to use Call Progress Events with PHP, C#, Ruby, Node.js, Java or - if you like kicking it command line style - a curl command.